# Mongodb recursive query for field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongodb and you can see document example in below

```
[
    {
      "_id": "6484f288cf6b203894bbea7a",
      "name": "test-1",
      "data": {
        "type": "10",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "20",
            "items": [
              {
                "type": "30",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "20",
                    "items": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": "6484f288cf6b203894bbea7a",
      "name": "test-2",
      "data": {
        "type": "10",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "10",
            "items": [
              {
                "type": "30",
                "items": [
                  {
                    "type": "40",
                    "items": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    ]
```

data field can be different for each document.It has 4 depth data above but it can be 20 for other document in collection.

I want to do that creating filter query for data field of this document.For example if data field has any type 20

I want to select each document name field if query match

For my collection output will be test-1 because test-2 document does not have type = 20 in data field

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to retrieve using filter query ?

Comment: I want to select name field of documents which is query match

Comment: what is your expected output? can you give proper example

Comment: As far as I know, there is no _efficient_ way to do this. It's also only even generally possible if there is some reasonable bound do the nesting. So if this type of search is going to be performed frequently or is found in part of the app that is sensitive to latency, then it is unlikely it will scale well as the number of documents grows.